# Java Spring Data @EnabledJPARepositories question

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data with Hibernate as JPA provider and have a class, this is a standalone app I'm not using Boot in this project.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={basePackages})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {com.company.dao.UserDao.class})
public class Company{
```

I am using a UserDao like this.

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends GenericDao<User>{    
   @Query("query")
   public int findByLoginAndPass(@Param("login") String login,@Param("password") String password);
}

public interface GenericDao<T extends AbstractEntity> extends CrudRepository<T,Integer>{    
}
```

This is working like a charm but later I create a VehiculeService which is also using the genericDAO.

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
@Transactional
public class VehiculeServiceImpl implements VehiculeService<Vehicule> {
  @Autowired
  private GenericDao<T> genericDao;

  @Override
  public T save(final T entity){
     return genericDao.save(entity);        
  }
}
```

This is working like a charm also, so what is the problem?

Both classes are using GenericDao which I don't use any Spring annotation right and in the configuration I am using

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {com.company.dao.UserDao.class})
```

And I see the genericDao as Spring managed bean in my configuration so the two questions are:

1). Why GenericDao is a managed bean in my context? Is extending CrudRepository but CrudRepository is a @NoRepositoryBean? If I don't extend the Interface CrudRepository my class is not longer a bean.

2). Why I can store Vehicules in my app even I don't state anything besides UserDao in the @EnabledJpaRepositories?

UserDao--->com.company.dao.UserDao
GenericDao-->com.company.dao.abstraction.GenericDao

If I say

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {com.company.dao.UserDao.class})
```

It will search where?

It's the first time I am using Spring Data from the scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because that's the principle of Spring Data JPA: It creates a bean for every scanned interface which extends Repository.
2. Because it's in the same package as UserDao, and you told JPA to scan the package containing the class UserDao: `basePackageClasses = {com.company.dao.UserDao.class}`.

Comment: But. The packages is like this. UserDao-->com.compay.dao and the GenericDao is com.company.dao.abstraction and i told spring to scan UserDao.class only? because i would understand if i told spring like this @EnableJpaRepositories("com.company.dao") i say it will search in the packages and in the subpackages but when i say .class it will search where??

Comment: No, you didn't. Read the javadoc of basePackageClasses. It explains what it does (which is what I said in my answer).